# How to handle, after state change in React context dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, use-reducer, use-context

I have a react version 16 application. The state changes are handled using React's Context, reducer concept.

To change the state and do something post that change can be handled as given below. For Example - I am in component 'Contact'. Inside this I am dispatching a state change on a variable age which is a number as given below -

```
dispatch({
    type: "CHANGE_AGE",
    payload: age
})
```

and catch the dispatch in the reducer as given below

```
case "CHANGE_AGE":
    return {
        ...state,
        age: action.payload
    }
```

To do something in 'Contact' component after there is a change in age, we can use 'useEffect' to watch for change in 'age'

```
useEffect({
    //doSomething()
},[state.age])
```

The problem is - What if we had to change an object in state, ie instead of changing the age, we had to change the address like given below and we had to do something after address has changed.

**How do we watch for a change in address?**

```
dispatch({
    type: "CHANGE_ADDRESS",
    payload: {
        city: "Delhi",
        country: "India",
        zip: '22233'
    }
})
```

One probable solution - Along with address dispatch, we can dispatch a variable, on change of which we can do something. But this is not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just store both: the previous and the current addresses

```
// your-state.js
const initialState = {
  age: 0,
  prevAdress: {
    city: '',
    country: '',
    zip: ''
  },
  currAdress: {
    city: '',
    country: '',
    zip: ''
  },
  ...
}
```

and when you dispatch, write current as previous in a reducer

```
// your-reducer.js
...
case "CHANGE_ADDRESS":
    return {
        ...state,
        prevAddress: { ...state.currAddress },
        currAddress: { ...action.payload }
    }
```

Then compare in the effect

```
// your-component.js
...
useEffect(() => {
  if (state.prevAddress.zip !== state.currAddress.zip) { // just an example of comparison
    // doSmthg
  }
}, [state]);
...
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to compare address only once and do something based on that comparison then just compare before dispatching a value:

```
// your-component.js
...
useEffect(() => {
  const doDispatch = () => dispatch({
        type: "CHANGE_ADDRESS",
        payload: {
          city: "Delhi",
          country: "India",
          zip: newZip,
        },
      });

  if (state.address.zip !== newZip) {
    doSmthgAsPromise().then(() => {     // do something and then dispatch
      doDispatch();
    });
  } else {
    doDispatch();
  }
}, [state, dispatch, doSmthgAsPromise]);
```

Comment: That's a nice approach. My Question - What if we had many state variables holding object values, should we have prev and current variables for each? Any other approach you can think of?

Comment: Well it depends on your purpose. I think you have to have prev/curr for each if you would like to compare them multiple times at different point of time. If you just want to check it once just see the solution in my **update**

Comment: I see your update. The only downside I see is that it will end up in many local state variables like newZip which we have to compare. Assuming my purpose is to update, and i could update potentially anything within that address object AND just like address object, if I have many other state variables(of object type)...?

Comment: I am not sure of what your final goal is. There is no "history" or "changelog" feature in React Context or `useReducer` hook. So the only way to track changes is to store them somewhere.